Insert data to table in C#
I've been working on a game for about 2 months now, and I'm using a SQL Server database to store all of the data about the player. I've been trying to write the data to a table called Players, and so far no success.
I tried creating a method in which I establish a connection with the database, and insert the data through SqlCommand (SqlClient).
DataManager class
public static void UpdatePlayerStatistics(string connectionString, string[] playerTextData, int[] playerIntData) 
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO dbo.Players VALUES ({playerTextData[0]})", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerName", playerTextData[0].ToString());

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}

Game class:
public static string[] playerTextData = new string[4];
/* 
 * 0 - PlayerFirstName
 * 1 - PlayerLastName
 * 2 - PlayerRace
 * 3 - PlayerClass
 */

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Receives player's first name
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character's first name: ");
    playerTextData[0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();

    // Receives player's last name
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character's last name: ");
    playerTextData[1] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();

    // Uploads the basic data to table
    DataManager.UpdatePlayerStatistics(playerTextData, playerIntData);
}

Also, when testing, I got this error

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid Column name <First Name>. Invalid column name <Last Name>. Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.


Don't use string concatenation to build an SQL command, at best it leads to problems like this and at worse it leads to SQL Injection attacks. Always parametrize your statements. You've defined a @PlayerName parameter but never use it.

You don't define what columns you are inserting into. What columns exist in the Players table? In addition, you might be making it harder on yourself to use an array to hold the player's first and last name. It might be easier to understand if you use different named variables and/or a class. It's quite arbitrary to say "in this array, index 0 just so happens to be the first name, and index 1 just so happens to be the last name".

Tagging this ssms is like telling us the car you drive is a sony, because that's the brand on the radio dashboard.

Also, it is NOT OKAY to use string interpolation or concatenation for including data in an sql command. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong, even for learning/practice/proof of concept work.

Finally, don't use string arrays for storing fields. Define a class with properties for each field. If you don't know to do that, you're not ready to learn to use databases yet.

Does this answer your question? Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?

There's a lot to do here. Notes as comments to explain changes.
// Do NOT use array elements as fields! Classes (or Records) are so much better for this.
public class PlayerData
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Race {get;set;}
    public string Class {get;set;}
}
// Again: if a class is this simple, with only basic auto-implemented properties, it should probably be a record.
// I left it as a class because someone new to C# may not have seen records yet.
// Also remember, you'll be able to re-use this class when going the other direction and selecting data back out of the database.

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create our player object closer to where it's used
        var player = new PlayerData();

        // Receives player's first name
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character's first name: ");
        player.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        // Receives player's last name
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your character's last name: ");
        player.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        // Uploads the basic data to table
        DataManager.UpdatePlayerStatistics(player);
    }
}

public class DataManager
{
    // private connection string. 
    // Now other types won't be able to connect on their own (no string).
    // This forces data access to go through your data manager, where it belongs.
    // Some apps may opt to have this set via a constructor, load it 
    // from a config file or similar, or use dependency injection
    private static string connectionString = "connection string here";

    // No longer need to pass connection string as an argument
    // Also, we can accept the PlayerData type, with nice named fields
    public static void UpdatePlayerStatistics(PlayerData player) 
    {
        // this could be *const* if we wanted... it will never change!
        // However, I had to guess at the column names.
        // Also note how I included the parameter variables in the string
        string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Players (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName);";
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        // Do NOT use AddWithValue() (it has a serious performance "gotcha" that can crop up)
        // DO use the exact database column type and size from the database
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = player.FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = player.LastName;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // No need to call .Close() because the using directive takes care of it in a better way
    }
}


i think the most simple way is :
                 ExampleEntities1 db = new ExampleEntities1();
                 Tbl(your table name) D = new Tbl(your table name)();
                 D.PlayerFirstName = TxtPlayerFirstName.Text;
                 D.PlayerLastName = TxtPlayerLastName.Text;
                 D.PlayerClass = TxtPlayerClass.Text;
                 D.PlayerRace = Convert.ToInt32(PlayerRace.Text);
                 db.Tbl(your table name).Add(D);
                 db.SaveChanges();
                 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

form this way you easily can add your date on winform to datebase

So many problems here: they're not using EF, they're not using WinForms, have not yet defined the class to match the table...
